# Is there a LookupSet equivalent in SQL Server 2008 ... NOT r2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

Just spent the day figuring out how to properly use the LookupSet method only to find out it isn't supported on my production database which is NOT running SQL Server 2008 R2 (it is just running ol' SQL Server 2008).

So, is there a way to re-produce the functionality so it will work with old SQL Server 2008?

Thanks - wg

Comment: For those of use not familiar with LookupSet, could you describe the functionality you want?  I believe the answer to your question is that you need another table with the set values -- which is the best way to implement the solution in a relational database anyway.

Comment: `LookupSet` is SSRS functionality added in 2008R2 that allows table lookups from a separate dataset: effectively a join at the application layer. This comes in handy when the datasets are from dramatically different sources and can't easily both be accessed by the same data access layer, usually due to security or different engines. (I.E. joining a SharePoint list to a SQL query.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff points out in the comments, this can usually be implemented in the SQL query. If the datasource for your target of the LookupSet is similar enough to the the main query, then you can accomplish this with a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or a [correlated subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your could write custom code - which I wouldn't recommend because it's probably simpler to combine the data relationally first in your query. If one of the data sources is non-relational, then use SSIS to get it into a table and then use a query to combine the two sets of data.